# How to get list of opened emails which I send through send grid in specific category in C#

Tags: c#, sendgrid

Is there way to get list of opened emails which are send through sendgrid in specific category in c#?

I have already tried:

According to support we can Event Webhook but is there way to use it in C#

also there is link 
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/filter_settings.html#-Open-Tracking

but how to use it in C#?

Also there are api for bounce 
https://sendgrid.com/api/bounces.get.xml

is there any for opened ?

also according to sendgrid there is api 
sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html

but this api only return when any email will be opened next time , 
but this is for future opened emails , my issue is that i have sent emails to user and they are already opened
and now i want to have list of those emails which have already opened

Comment: WRT "is there way to use it in C#", "how to use it in C#": have you **actually tried** anything? Do you have code that has issues? What issues?

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html  i tried to do the event notification but i think this will work when next time user will open the email , but i want to know the list of emails which are already opend by user

Comment: You might want to try a templating/analytics service on top of SendGrid. Checkout [sendwithus](https://www.sendwithus.com), they track emails/opens/clicks by user and support SendGrid categories.